# How to change fun page tab name that has more than one row of characters in new FB

Tags: iframe, tabs, fbml

Now that Facebook has improved fan page I cannot change the tab name in the usual way. When I try to add more characters to tab name i can only see the first 20-25 characters. In the previous version it was done by clicking the edit page -> apps -> edit settings, and then if the line is too long it was displayed in two lines. Now that is not the case....

How to change tab name that has more than 25 characters in the new version of FB fun page? 
I need to display all of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced that this is currently a bug. Very similar if not the exact same [bug reported here](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16223).

I would suggest that you vote for that bug and attach your own (updated) screenshots.

Comment: It is not similar problem. I have a problem on the very fan page, because FB doesn't display the full tab name even if i change it to custom name from edit page->apps->etc...

It only displays first 25 or so characters...